# Why does fgets fail when I use 0 as FILE* to read from stdin in rop chain?

Tags: stack-overflow, exploit

I am making a [rop chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) to call fgets with stdin as input to be able to make a basic stack overflow.

But my issue is that when I call fgets with 0 as the third argument (for stdin) fgets crash at

```
 <fgets+49>       mov    ecx, DWORD PTR [esi]
```

where esi is the third argument I control, why does it crash? With 0 it should not try to read the content of it and just read from stdin, no?

The useful part of my ropchain looks like :

```
fgets.plt
pop_pop_pop_ret
buffer
0x500
0
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work.
The call made is something like :

```
_IO_fgets(buf=0xf7f77000, n=0x500, fp=0x0)
```

Comment: Calling `fgets()` with a null pointer for its third argument invokes undefined behaviour.  You're not allowed to pass a null pointer to almost any standard C library that expects a `FILE *` (the main (only?) exception is `fflush()` — that has a defined behaviour when the argument is a null pointer).  Don't do it; programs are likely to crash.  If you want `fgets()` to read from `stdin`, pass `stdin` as the third argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `stdin` is not a number. It's an object in `libc`.

```
zeltrax@ubuntu:~$ readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep "stdin"
377: 00000000001eb980   224 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   31 _IO_2_1_stdin_@@GLIBC_2.2.5
546: 00000000001ec790     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   31 stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Check this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        printf("stdin : %p\n", stdin);
        printf("printf: %p\n", printf);
        
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
zeltrax@ubuntu:~$ gcc test.c
zeltrax@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out
stdin : 0x7fcec21dc980
printf: 0x7fcec2055e10
```